# cognos: database view and business view

Tags: cognos-8

as fas as I know, in Framework Manager, the first step to build the database view.

In the second step:
is to build business view

why they done? what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

IBM has [a large section on their help devoted to Framework Manager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.10.1.1.doc/t_frameworkmanager.html), but it's a bit generic.

I [wrote a blog post on Framework Manager modeling guidelines](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2012/07/cognos-modeling-guidelines-and-standards.html) which may be a bit more useful for you..